# Mensagem de erro - Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php, wordpress, script

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:..\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\1\inc\tempo.php on line 6

No arquivo tempo.php na linha 6

eu tenho esse codigo

```
     <?php
/* TEMPAT CODE RECENT POST */

/* == MISC  == */
function usagilabs_category(){
    $category = get_the_category()[0];
    echo '<a href="'. esc_url(home_url( '/anime/' ) . esc_attr( $category->slug )) .'" title="see all '.esc_attr( $category->name ).'">'.esc_html( $category->name ).'</a>';
}

function usagilabs_seeall(){
    $category = get_the_category()[0];
    echo '<a href="'. esc_url(home_url( '/anime/' ) . esc_attr( $category->slug )) .'" title="see all episode '.esc_attr( $category->name ).'">',get_option('config_seeall')?:'See All Episode','</a>'; 
}

function usagilabs_search(){
    echo '<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="',esc_url(home_url('/')),'">';
    echo '<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="',esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder'),'" value="',get_search_query(),'" name="s" />';
    echo '<select id="pilih" name="post_type"><option value="anime">Anime</option><option value="post">Episode</option></select>';
    echo '</form>';
}

function usagilabs_searchs(){
    echo '<form role="search" method="get" class="searchs-form" action="',esc_url(home_url('/')),'">';
    echo '<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="',esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder'),'" value="',get_search_query(),'" name="s" />';
    echo '<select id="pilih" name="post_type"><option value="anime">Anime</option><option value="post">Episode</option></select>';
    echo '</form>';
}

/* == REKOMENDASI ANIME == */
function usagilabs_recomended(){
    echo '<b>',get_option('recom_title')?:'Recommended :','</b>';
    $rekomendasi = new WP_Query(
    array(
    'post_type' => get_option('recom_posttype')?:'anime',
    'orderby'   => 'rand',
    'showposts'   => get_option('recom_num_post')?:'6'
    ));
    while($rekomendasi->have_posts()) : $rekomendasi->the_post();
    the_title( sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="recom-title">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a>' );
    endwhile;
}

/* == HOT UPDATE == */
function usagilabs_hotupdate(){
    echo '<div id="hotupdate"><div class="hotupdates row row-flex">';
            $hotupdate = new WP_Query(
            array(
            'post_type' => get_option('hot_posttype')?:'post',
            'orderby'   => 'modified',
            'showposts'   => get_option('hot_num_post')?:'6',           
            'category_name' => get_option('hot_categ')?:'Uncategorized',
            ));
            if($hotupdate->have_posts()) : while($hotupdate->have_posts()) : $hotupdate->the_post();    

    echo '<div class="hotupdate-posts col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">';
    echo '<div class="hotupdate-thumb">';
    echo '<a href="', the_permalink() ,'" title="',the_title() ,'">';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
             the_post_thumbnail( array( 153, 202, true, array( 'center', 'center' ), 'class' => 'thumbnail', 'alt' => get_the_title() ) );
            } else {
                echo '<img src="',get_template_directory_uri(),'/lib/img/no_anim.png" class="thumbnail no-img" alt="Thumbnail no image">';
        }
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<h3 class="hotupdate-title">';
         the_title( sprintf( '<a class="eps" href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a>' ); 
    echo '</h3>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
         endwhile; else : 
    echo '<div class="site-error"><p>',get_option('hot_error_notice')?:'No latest hottest anime','</p></div>';
    endif; 
    echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
    echo '</div></div>';
}

/* == PAGINASI == */
function usagilabs_pagination(){
    echo '<span class="anipager-prev">', previous_post_link('%link', get_option('config_prev')?:'<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Previous', true) ,'</span>';
    echo '<span class="anipager-seeall">', usagilabs_seeall() ,'</span>';
    echo '<span class="anipager-next">', next_post_link('%link', get_option('config_next')?:'Next <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>', true) ,'</span>';
}

/* == DOWNLOAD BOX == */
function usagilabs_download(){
            if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_check_720p', true) != 'on'){
                echo '<div class="entry-download-item">';
                    echo '<div class="entry-download-title">',get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_name_720p', true)?:'720P','</div>';
                    echo '<div class="entry-download-link">';
                    // LINK 1
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link1_720p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="',get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link1_720p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_720p_name1')?:'Solidfiles','</a> | ';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_720p_name1')?:'Solidfiles','</del> | ';}
                    // LINK 2
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link2_720p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link2_720p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_720p_name2')?:'Savefile','</a> | ';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_720p_name2')?:'Savefile','</del> | ';}
                    // LINK 3
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link3_720p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link3_720p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_720p_name3')?:'Zippyshare','</a> | ';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_720p_name3')?:'Zippyshare','</del> | ';}
                    // LINK 4
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link4_720p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link4_720p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_720p_name4')?:'Mirrorcreator','</a>';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_720p_name4')?:'Mirrorcreator','</del>';}
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                }               
            if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_check_480p', true) != 'on'){
                echo '<div class="entry-download-item">';
                    echo '<div class="entry-download-title">',get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_name_480p', true)?:'480P','</div>';
                    echo '<div class="entry-download-link">';                   
                    // LINK 1
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link1_480p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link1_480p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_480p_name1')?:'Solidfiles','</a> | ';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_480p_name1')?:'Solidfiles','</del> | ';}
                    // LINK 2
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link2_480p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link2_480p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_480p_name2')?:'Savefile','</a> | ';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_480p_name2')?:'Savefile','</del> | ';}
                    // LINK 3
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link3_480p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link3_480p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_480p_name3')?:'Zippyshare','</a> | ';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_480p_name3')?:'Zippyshare','</del> | ';}
                    // LINK 4
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link4_480p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link4_480p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_480p_name4')?:'Mirrorcreator','</a>';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_480p_name4')?:'Mirrorcreator','</del>';}                  
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                }
            if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_check_360p', true) != 'on'){
                echo '<div class="entry-download-item">';
                    echo '<div class="entry-download-title">',get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_name_360p', true)?:'360P','</div>';
                    echo '<div class="entry-download-link">';                   
                    // LINK 1
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link1_360p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link1_360p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_360p_name1')?:'Solidfiles','</a> | ';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_360p_name1')?:'Solidfiles','</del> | ';}
                    // LINK 2
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link2_360p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link2_360p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_360p_name2')?:'Savefile','</a> | ';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_360p_name2')?:'Savefile','</del> | ';}
                    // LINK 3
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link3_360p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link3_360p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_360p_name3')?:'Zippyshare','</a> | ';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_360p_name3')?:'Zippyshare','</del> | ';}
                    // LINK 4
                    if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link4_360p', true))){
                    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dl_link4_360p', true).'" target="_blank">',get_option('config_360p_name4')?:'Mirrorcreator','</a>';
                    }else{echo '<del>',get_option('config_360p_name4')?:'Mirrorcreator','</del>';}                  
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                }
}
?>
<?php function usagilabs_info(){ ?>
        <div class="anime-info-parent col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <?php // METHOD 1
            foreach((get_the_category()) as $anim_slug){
            $animu = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'anime','s' => $anim_slug->cat_name,'showposts' => '1'));
            while($animu->have_posts()) : $animu->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="animinf-parent-post">
            <div class="animinf-parent-thumb">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php
            if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                the_post_thumbnail(array(130, 180, 'class' => 'theme-thumbnail', 'alt' => get_the_title() ));
            } else {
                echo '<img height="130" width="180" src="',get_template_directory_uri(),'/lib/img/no_anim.png" class="thumbnail no-img" alt="Thumbnail no image">';
            }
            ?>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="animinf-parent-box">
            <h2 class="animinf-parent-title"><?php the_title( sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a>' ); ?></h2>
            <footer class="animinf-parent-footer">
            <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, '...' ); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'type', '<b>Tipe </b>: '); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'episode', '<b>Episode </b>: '); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'status', '<b>Status </b>: '); ?></p>
            </footer>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div></div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); }?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="anime-info-child col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
            <?php  // METHOD 2
            $anim =  get_the_category(); $anim_slug = $anim[0]->slug;
            $animu = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'anime','post__not_in' => array($anim_slug),'showposts' => '3','orderby' => 'rand'));
            while($animu->have_posts()) : $animu->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="animinf-child-posts">
            <div class="animinf-child-thumb">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php 
            if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                the_post_thumbnail(array(50, 'class' => 'theme-thumbnail', 'alt' => get_the_title() ));
            } else {
                echo '<img height="50" width="50" src="',get_template_directory_uri(),'/lib/img/no_size.png" class="thumbnail no-img" alt="Thumbnail no image">';
            }
            ?>
            </a>
            </div>
            <h2 class="animinf-child-title"><?php the_title( sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a>' ); ?></h2>
            <div class="animinf-child-genre"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'genre','',', ')?:'Undefined',5); ?></div>
            <div class="clear"></div></div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>          
        </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Qual seria o erro do codigo? o arquivo é grande mas a parte que se refere a linha 6 é essa ai

Codigo

Comment: Poderia postar a função `get_the_category()`?

Comment: Você quer que poste o codigo inteiro?

Comment: Só com as informações passadas não tem como saber de onde vem o erro. Poste a função `get_the_category()`.

Comment: Postei, da uma olhada

Comment: Você postou tudo menos a função `get_the_category()`, recomendo ver se ela realmente existe.

Comment: Onde vou encontra essa parte? no function.php ?

Comment: Qual a versão do PHP? Está sintaxe só é permitida a partir da versão 5.4. Acredito que a sua seja anterior a esta.

Comment: A versão do php é PHP Version 5.3.2

Comment: @Endou o PHP 5.3 está obsoleto e sem suporte desde 2014. Mude para o 5.6 ou 7 que são as versões que ainda recebem atualizações de segurança. Se seu host não mudar, mude de host.

Comment: Estou usando  o programa InstantWP_4.5 que vem com essa versão do PHP,  tentei atualiza manualmente o php e quando faço isso o worpress para de funciona. esse programa é para usar o wordpress em local host

Answer (score 0):

O correto é usar da seguinte maneira

```
function usagilabs_category(){
$category = get_the_category();
echo '<a href="'. esc_url(home_url( '/anime/' ) . esc_attr( $category[0]->slug )) .'" title="see all '.esc_attr( $category[0]->name ).'">'.esc_html( $category[0]->name ).'</a>';
}
```

pois esta é uma função retorna um array e não um atributo do tipo array.

Comment: Acontece que eu baixei esse tema e não mexi em nada. coloquei na pasta do wordpress mas quando tento ativa da esse erro.

Comment: Alterei essa parte e agora ta dando o mesmo erro na linha 11

Comment: pois a função usagilabs_seeall esta da mesma forma

Comment: Alterei a parte em usagilabs_seeall e apareceu outros erros em outras partes